# Python: Iterate over many large files simultaneusly, get every k-th line

Tags: python, python-itertools

As in the title - I have many very large text files (>10GB) that have the same, repetitive structure. I would like to filter some information out so I would like to yield every k-th line from them but iterating over them all at the same time. I have tried itertools: islice and izip, but I cannot put them together...

Comment: Please include your attempt; it is much more productive to point out your specific error than repeat stuff you already figured out.

Comment: You can divide this task into three sub-tasks, first - iterate through files using multiprocessing, and store k-th lines into separate files, second - concatenate all files into one, and finally, third - iterate through second step output and yield results.

Comment: @vovaminiof: this is trivially solvable with just `itertools` however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you talk about using `itertools.izip()`, I'm going to assume you are using Python 2 here.

Use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to facilitate skipping lines from files, and the [`itertools.izip_longest()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html#future_builtins.izip_longest) to lazily combine reading in parallel as well as handle files that are shorter:

```
from itertools import islice, izip_longest

filenames = [fname1, fname2, fname3]
open_files = [open(fname) for fname in filenames]
kth_slice_files = (islice(f, None, None, k) for f in open_files)
try:
    for kth_lines in izip_longest(*kth_slice_files, fillvalue=''):
        # do something with those combined lines
```

`islice(fileobj, None, None, k)` will start at the *first* line, then skip `k - 1` lines to give you the 1 + k, then 1 + 2*k, etc. lines. If you need to start at a later line, replace the first `None` with that starting value.