# How to make it so that loop starts at index 150 and prints 20 values from the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.6

```
def corona(data,lenght,abstand,temperatur):
    file = open('/home/rezan/Downloads/MSA_SARS2_20200329.consensus.fasta','r')
    list = []
    list1 = []

    for i in file:
        ls = i.strip()
        list.append(ls)

        for l in i:
            list1.append(l.strip())
        while '' in list1:
            list1.remove('')
        while '' in list:
            list1.remove('')

    temp = temperatur
    for w in list:
        if temp == (2* w[0:laenge].count('A') + 
                    2* w[:laenge].count('T') + 
                    4* w[0:laenge].count('G') +  
                    4* w[0:laenge].count('C')):
            print((w[0:laenge]))


corona('/home/rezan/Downloads/MSA_SARS2_20200329.consensus.fasta',20,150,60)
```

I got this output:

```
CCGGGTGTGANCGAAAGGTA
TTCGGANGCTCGAACTGCAC
AGGCATTCAGTACGGTCGTA
TGATGGCTACCCTCTTGAGT
CACTTTGTCCGAACAACTGG
CACACTCAAAGGCNGTGCAC
TGTTGTGGCAGATGCTGTCA
GGGTGTTTTAACTGCTGTGG
GGGTGTGGTTGATTATGGTG
AATGGCCCCGATTTCAGCTA
TGCAACTGCAGAAGCTGAAC
TATTTCAGCAGCTCGGCAAG
TCTCGCAAAGGCTCTCAATG
AGTTCATGCTGGCACAGACT
AATGCTGGACAACAGGGCAA
TGATGCAGCCATGCAACGTA
GGCTAGATTCCCTAAGAGTG
TACACAATGGCAGACCTCGT
TTCATACAAACCACGCCAGG
TGCAATGCTCCAGGTTGTGA
GGTAAACCTAGACCACCACT
GACACTGTGAGTGCTTTGGT
CTATGTGATAGACGTGCCAC
CTTCACGACATTGGTAACCC
GACAGTCCATGTGAGTCTCA
GATGCGCAAACAGGTTCATC
AAAGGAGTTGCACCAGGTAC
AGGGGTACTGCTGTTATGTC
GACCCAGTCCCTACTTATTG
GAACTTCACAACTGCTCCTG
GCACAAGCTGATGAGTACGA
GTTTGGTGGACCCTCAGATT
CACTCAACATGGCAAGGAAG
CAATAGCAGTCCAGATGACC
GGGAGCCTTGAATACACCAA
GAAGCCTCGGCAAAAACGTA
```

But I want that python starts with the 150 value in list and not at beginning and hold the length of 20.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Iterate over many large files simultaneusly, get every k-th line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021352/python-iterate-over-many-large-files-simultaneusly-get-every-k-th-line)

Comment: That code doesn't match the output because `laenge` is undefined and raises a `NameError`. The names are bad. `list1` isn't used anywhere. The first `while` loop to remove empty strings would be inefficient. But there can't be any empty strings in that list anyway. If that could be, the second `while` loop would be an endless loop.

Comment: It was a mistake from stakeoverflow→ lenght/laenge

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can try to use itertools.islice. I won't rewrite your code with all the formating, but i will put up an example on how to do it.

```
import itertools

start_index = 150
end_index = start_index + 20

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in itertools.islice(f, start_index, end_index):
        print(line) # This will print out lines from start_index to end_index
```